# Filter And Pagination With Carraydataprovider

Tags: php, yii

I have been trying to use CArrayDataprovider with filter and pagination. This works all fine when i first load the page.

The problem starts when I use my search. The first time it loads the data correctly. But once I paginate from the page, it loads all the data. Not the ones that were searched for. Below is my code:

Controller:

```
public function actionTest() {
    /* pagination with CArrayDataProvider */
    $sql = $this->searchLogs();

    $callLogs = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();

    $dp = new CArrayDataProvider($callLogs, array(
        'keyField' => 'ticket_id',
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ),
    ));

    $this->render('test', array(
        'model' => $dp,
    ));
}
```

View:

```
<?php
    $gridWidget = $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $model,
        'columns' => array(

            'id: Id',
            'name: Name',
            'mobile: Mobile',
            'created_date: Created Date',
            array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
                'header' => 'Operations',
                'template' => '{view}',

            ),
        ),
    ));
    ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below the link. I think it will fill your requirements.

http://bmweb90.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-setup-drop-down-for-page-size-in.html

Comment: I think thats not the answer to my question. I have a problem with pagination using CArrayDataprovider.